# How do I make DOIs in a bilbliography move to a new line if there is not room for it without breaking on the current line instead of breaking?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-breaking

There are many questions about how to get URLs and DOIs in bibliographies to break properly. ([This one seems like it should help, but I don't see how to use it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/7880)

My DOIs *are* breaking correctly, but I'm not happy with the result and want to try an alternative.

I would like it if my DOIs were shunted to a new line if they would cause a linebreak, but not if they would then still fill up the entire line, since that doesn't improve the situation.

[I've been told that the answer to this question can be adapted, but I'm not sure how to work that into the bibliography to be honest.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247937/7880) (Or, indeed what most of the code is doing in it, it has a lot of definitions and no documentation.)

Here is an example that generates a DOI that splits over a line, but doesn't *need* to if it was on a new line. Then the same total number of lines would be used, but it would be easier to copy/paste the DOI (if for example, my hyperlinks wound up broken by a PDF processing program down the line, which I've seen happen before when someone wants to mass-insert a copyright page or something).

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage[left= 4 cm, right=4 cm]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@inproceedings{Meshlab,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-rsc,
    doi=true,
    articletitle=true,
    pageranges=true,
]{biblatex} 

\def\UrlFont{\rm} %Make the URL font roman instead of typewriter, so DOI in body and bib are the same size. 

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}\autocite{Meshlab}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe that's enough to add a clickable short link like the term "DOI" pointing to the right page? Like `\href{10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}{DOI}`? All this very long DOI information seems useless to me.

Comment: Instead of `\def\UrlFont{\rm}` I'd say `\urlstyle{same}`, that's the interface the `url` documentation suggests for the easy cases. (Of course that has nothing to do with your actual question, but might still be interesting.)

Comment: @pluton The advantage of using a text DOI is that if the main server goes offline (which has happened) the chemistry community maintains backups, so you can still get to the paper without a lot of work.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a couple of options:

### 1. Make your bibliography `\raggedright`

Just add `\AtBeginBibliography{\raggedright}` to you preamble.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left= 4 cm, right=4 cm]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Meshlab,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
@inproceedings{Meshlab2,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap}
}
@inproceedings{Meshlab3,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI =
    {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    style=chem-rsc,
    doi=true,
    articletitle=true,
    pageranges=true,
]{biblatex} 

\def\UrlFont{\rm}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{\raggedright}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

### 2. Encourage a break before the DOI.

You can set the DOI field format using some code slightly modified from the *TeX Book* to encourage a break before it:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hbox{}\nobreak
  DOI\addcolon\addnbspace
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

The `\hfil` creates a space if the DOI does fit on the final line, so we try and mitigate this with an `\hfill` at the end of the record:

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentry\hfill\null}
```

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left= 4 cm, right=4 cm]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Meshlab,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
@inproceedings{Meshlab2,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap}
}
@inproceedings{Meshlab3,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI =
    {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    style=chem-rsc,
    doi=true,
    articletitle=true,
    pageranges=true,
]{biblatex} 

\def\UrlFont{\rm}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hbox{}\nobreak
  DOI\addcolon\addnbspace
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentry\hfill\null}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I'm getting a lot of issues with this answer. It appears to work pretty much only in the specific MWE above, if the length of the text *other* then the DOI changes I get the DOI moving to a new line despite lots of space being left, or a big chunk of whitespace before the DOI. 

Should I add these to the MWE above with an image?

Comment: @Canagreek, I would have thought the ragged right option would be reliable. But add some other examples and see if you get a better answer. I can look at it again too.

Comment: @Canageek Well, `\raggedright` does a little more than just change your DOIs. It effectively turns off justification (in Word terms is switched from 'justify' to 'align left'). This may indeed be a bit excessive if you only wanted to influence the DOI, but given your other recent questions where you ask about disabling a few other break points giving up justification (i.e. going with `\raggedright`) may be your only option if you don't want to be stuck with many massively overfull or overfull boxes.

Comment: @Canageek, ah yes. I didn't think carefully enough about shorter DOIs. the `\hfil` is responsible for the big white space. :(

Comment: @Canageek, it's a bit of a hack, but what if you add `\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentry\hfill\null}` to your preamble?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try the ragged right, I was talking about the second option, I like the justification.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left= 4 cm, right=4 cm]{geometry}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@inproceedings{Meshlab,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-rsc,
    doi=true,
    articletitle=true,
    pageranges=true,
]{biblatex} 

\renewcommand*\UrlFont{\sffamily}
%\renewcommand*\UrlFont{\ttfamily\small}
\newcommand*\doi[1]{{\UrlFont #1}}

\renewcommand*\bibsetup{\raggedright}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\addnbspace
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item DOI = \doi{10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}\autocite{Meshlab}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

That is:

- Make the bibliography `\raggedright`.
- Forbid a line break between "DOI:" and the DOI. For this, I copied the definition of the `doi` field format from `biblatex.def` and replaced `\space` with `\addnbspace`. (This is not necessary to prevent the DOI from breaking, but I find it much nicer for the "DOI:" to also move to the next line.)

Further recommendations:

- I like to use either `\ttfamily\small` (which fits nicer with the default roman font than just `\ttfamily`) or `\sffamily` (which matches the overwhelmingly dominant use of sans serif fonts online) for URLs.
- Instead of making the URL font match your normal font, you can just print DOIs in URL font everywhere.
- Another option could be to print the bibliography in a slightly smaller font than the rest of the document (e.g. `10pt` instead of `11pt`), making fewer line breaks necessary overall. Be very careful with this, though.