# Move entire DOI to the next line rather then sticking into the margin

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, doi, biblatex-chem

This builds off [a previous question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566160/how-do-i-make-dois-in-a-bilbliography-move-to-a-new-line-if-there-is-not-room-fo) that didn't get an answer that would work for me. I've simplified what I am asking for.

When a DOI in my bibliography extends into the margin, instead of doing that, can it be booted to the next line, and a blank space left on the current line?

Here is an example of the problem: [image: An 8 entry bibliography with 2 entries sticking into the magine as the final part of them is quite long.]

Based on the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[width=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc,doi=true,articletitle=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{VESTA,
author = "Momma, Koichi and Izumi, Fujio",
title = "{{\it VESTA3} for three-dimensional visualization of crystal, volumetric and morphology data}",
journal = "J. App. Cryst.",
year = "2011",
volume = "44",
number = "6",
pages = "1272--1276",
doi = {10.1107/S0021889811038970}
}
@Article{Charpin1985,
  author  = {Charpin, P. and Folcher, G. and Lance, M. and Nierlich, M. and Vigner, D.},
  title   = {Structure d'un complexe binucl\'{e}aire du nitrate d'uranyle et du N,N-dim\'{e}thyl-formamide: \(\mu\)-peroxo-bis[bis(N,N-dim\'{e}thyl-formamide)nitratodioxouranium(VI)], [(UO2)2(NO3)2O2(C3H7NO)4]},
  journal = {Acta Crystallogr. Sect.~C: Struct. Chem.},
  year    = {1985},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {1302--1305},
  doi     = {10.1107/S0108270185007533},
}
@Article{Kawasaki2015,
  author  = {Kawasaki, Takeshi and Kitazawa, Takafumi},
  title   = {Crystal structure of Long Chemical Name Long Chemical Name Long that would need another package to print here asdfasdf},
  journal = {Acta Crystallogr., Sect.~E: Struct. Rep. Online},
  year    = {2015},
  volume  = {71},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {m122--m123},
  doi     = {10.1107/S2056989015007987},
}
@inproceedings{Meshlab,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
@Article{Vittal2011,
  author  = {Leong, Wei Lee and Vittal, Jagadese J.},
  title   = {One-Dimensional Coordination Polymers: Complexity and Diversity in Structures, Properties, and Applications},
  journal = {Chem. Rev.},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {111},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {688--764},
  doi     = {10.1021/cr100160e},
}
@article{Xu2018,
author = {Xu, Wei and Ren, Ya Nan and Xie, Miao and Zhou, Lin Xia and Zheng, Yue Qing},
doi = {10.1039/c7dt04909a},
journal = {Dalton Trans.},
number = {12},
pages = {4236--4250},
publisher = {Royal Society of Chemistry},
title = {{Six uranyl-organic frameworks with naphthalene-dicarboxylic acid and bipyridyl-based spacers: Syntheses, structures, and properties}},
volume = {47},
year = {2018}
}
@Article{HBond,
  author  = {Steiner, Thomas},
  title   = {The Hydrogen Bond in the Solid State},
  journal = {Angew. Chem., Int. Ed.},
  year    = {2002},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {48--76},
  doi     = {10.1002/1521-3773(20020104)41:1<48::AID-ANIE48>3.0.CO;2-U},
}
@Article{rigu,
  author  = {Thorn, Andrea and Dittrich, Birger and Sheldrick, George M.},
  title   = {Enhanced rigid-bond restraints},
  journal = {Acta Crystallogr. Sect.~A: Foundations and Advances},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {68},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {448--451},
  doi     = {10.1107/S0108767312014535},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
How do I get BibLaTeX to stop putting the DOI in the margin?

The first paper is fine, since it breaks nicely into the next line.\autocite{VESTA}

However, the next two\autocite{Charpin1985,Kawasaki2015} give me problems since the part of the DOI after the / is so long. 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The multiple examples are included, as I was given code that should do something similar to this last time, but it broke rapidly when given DOIs of different lengths and compositions.

The MWE again, showing what I want to avoid:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[width=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc,doi=true,articletitle=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hbox{}\nobreak
  DOI\addcolon\addnbspace
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{VESTA,
author = "Momma, Koichi and Izumi, Fujio",
title = "{{\it VESTA3} for three-dimensional visualization of crystal, volumetric and morphology data}",
journal = "J. App. Cryst.",
year = "2011",
volume = "44",
number = "6",
pages = "1272--1276",
doi = {10.1107/S0021889811038970}
}
@Article{Charpin1985,
  author  = {Charpin, P. and Folcher, G. and Lance, M. and Nierlich, M. and Vigner, D.},
  title   = {Structure d'un complexe binucl\'{e}aire du nitrate d'uranyle et du N,N-dim\'{e}thyl-formamide: \(\mu\)-peroxo-bis[bis(N,N-dim\'{e}thyl-formamide)nitratodioxouranium(VI)], [(UO2)2(NO3)2O2(C3H7NO)4]},
  journal = {Acta Crystallogr. Sect.~C: Struct. Chem.},
  year    = {1985},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {1302--1305},
  doi     = {10.1107/S0108270185007533},
}
@Article{Kawasaki2015,
  author  = {Kawasaki, Takeshi and Kitazawa, Takafumi},
  title   = {Crystal structure of Long Chemical Name Long Chemical Name Long that would need another package to print here asdfasdf},
  journal = {Acta Crystallogr., Sect.~E: Struct. Rep. Online},
  year    = {2015},
  volume  = {71},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {m122--m123},
  doi     = {10.1107/S2056989015007987},
}
@inproceedings{Meshlab,
    booktitle = {Eurographics Italian Chapter Conference},
    editor = {Vittorio Scarano and Rosario De Chiara and Ugo Erra},
    title = {{MeshLab: an Open-Source Mesh Processing Tool}},
    author = {Cignoni, Paolo and Callieri, Marco and Corsini, Massimiliano and Dellepiane, Matteo and Ganovelli, Fabio and Ranzuglia, Guido},
    year = {2008},
    publisher = {The Eurographics Association},
    ISBN = {978-3-905673-68-5},
    DOI = {10.2312/LocalChapterEvents/ItalChap/ItalianChapConf2008/129-136}
}
@Article{Vittal2011,
  author  = {Leong, Wei Lee and Vittal, Jagadese J.},
  title   = {One-Dimensional Coordination Polymers: Complexity and Diversity in Structures, Properties, and Applications},
  journal = {Chem. Rev.},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {111},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {688--764},
  doi     = {10.1021/cr100160e},
}
@article{Xu2018,
author = {Xu, Wei and Ren, Ya Nan and Xie, Miao and Zhou, Lin Xia and Zheng, Yue Qing},
doi = {10.1039/c7dt04909a},
journal = {Dalton Trans.},
number = {12},
pages = {4236--4250},
publisher = {Royal Society of Chemistry},
title = {{Six uranyl-organic frameworks with naphthalene-dicarboxylic acid and bipyridyl-based spacers: Syntheses, structures, and properties}},
volume = {47},
year = {2018}
}
@Article{HBond,
  author  = {Steiner, Thomas},
  title   = {The Hydrogen Bond in the Solid State},
  journal = {Angew. Chem., Int. Ed.},
  year    = {2002},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {48--76},
  doi     = {10.1002/1521-3773(20020104)41:1<48::AID-ANIE48>3.0.CO;2-U},
}
@Article{rigu,
  author  = {Thorn, Andrea and Dittrich, Birger and Sheldrick, George M.},
  title   = {Enhanced rigid-bond restraints},
  journal = {Acta Crystallogr. Sect.~A: Foundations and Advances},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {68},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {448--451},
  doi     = {10.1107/S0108767312014535},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
In this case, \autocite{VESTA} takes a different approach, moving the whole DOI to the next line. 
This allows both\autocite{Charpin1985,Kawasaki2015} to work perfectly. 
However, note what happens further down\autocite{Vittal2011,Xu2018}
 with short DOIs getting way to much space. 
 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The same image showing what I want to avoid.]

As you can see, bibliographies appear touchy, so I thought it was better to include a few test-cases.
Now, instead of trying to move every DOI that is too long to the next line (as that seems hard, and, to be fair, leaves a ton of extra white space in my references section), I only want to move the DOI down a line *if* it would protrude into the margin. Oh, and I would like the DOI: to move with it, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \hfil\penalty90\hfilneg\space DOI\addcolon\addnbspace
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

If the linebreak happens at the penalty, you get `\hfil` to pad out the short line. If it doesn't then the `\hfil` and `\hfilneg` cancel each other so you just get a normal inter-word space from `\space`. If the DOI are definitely short enough to fit on one line you could put an `\mbox{}` around `#1` to make sure it doesn't break, as is it could still break if needed.

(Edit on 14 April 2022: adjusted penalty from 50 to 90.)

Comment: Perfect, and it adds less then a page after 168 citations so I don't have to feel bad about the extra space.