# Move entire URL to the next line rather than sticking into the margin

Tags: bibliographies, urls

Based off the same issue and MWE provided in:

[Move entire DOI to the next line rather than sticking into the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572412/move-entire-doi-to-the-next-line-rather-then-sticking-into-the-margin)

would you indicate how to achieve the same result for any URL as opposed to just a DOI?  For example, replace any of the DOI={whatever} with URL={https://www.jstor.org/stable/248204_this_URL_is_tooooooooooooooo_long}.

Update: solved with this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \hfil\penalty90\hfilneg\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Provided by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572416/161015

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \hfil\penalty90\hfilneg\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable for a fast proof ...